# Find title of element

Tags: java, xpath, selenium-webdriver

Please someone help to solve following:

I have this HTML

```
<div class="author medium-3 small-12 column padding-reset tip-list-row__author">
<a href="https://expert.com/user/profile/pulkovo124" class="author-rating left" data-rating="2" data-modal="user-modal" data-user- id="465043"><canvas width="66" height="66" class="author-rating-visual user-rating-visual"></canvas>
<abbr title="Rating 2/5">
```

Found element with this xpath:

```
//div[@class='author medium-3 small-12 column padding-reset tip-list-row__author']/a/abbr[@title]
```

But when I want to print text of a title **Rating 2/5**, get xpath instead of text:

```
 xpath: //div[@class='author medium-3 small-12 column padding-reset tip-list-row__author']/a/abbr[@title]]
```

What am I doing wrong? Thank you in advance

Here is my code:

```
List<WebElement> allrates = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//div[@class='author medium-3 small-12 column padding-reset tip-list-row__author']/a/abbr[@title]"));
    List<WebElement> allusers = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//div[@class='author-name']/a"));

    for (int i = 0; i < alltips; i++) {
        String all = allrates.get(i).getText();
        String users = allusers.get(i).getText();
        System.out.println("User " + users + " has a rate " + all);
        Thread.sleep(500);

    }
```

Comment: We can only guess what you're doing wrong... Show your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To print text of a title **Rating 2/5** you can use the following code block :

```
List<WebElement> allrates = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//div[@class='author medium-3 small-12 column padding-reset tip-list-row__author']/a//abbr"));
List<WebElement> allusers = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//div[@class='author-name']/a"));
for (int i = 0; i < alltips; i++) 
{
    String all = allrates.get(i).getAttribute("title");
    String users = allusers.get(i).getText();
    System.out.println("User " + users + " has a rate " + all);
}
```

> **Note** : I have kept the other lines of code untouched